# I need to find and delete duplicate records of a set below

Tags: mysql

```
 -----------------------------------
| col 1     |     col2              |
 -----------------------------------
|val1       |    null               |
|val2       |    null               |
|val1       |    null               |
|null       |    val related to val1|
|null       |    val related to val2|
|null       |    val related to val3|
|val3       |    null               |
|val1       |    null               |
 ----------------------------------
```

I need distinct records from both the columns, I have 7 distinct records in col1 and 3 distinct records in col2. I need only those from the set.

I tried self join to fetch the unique records but the result set was not as expected.
Please help if I am doing anything wrong or do I need to follow any other approach.

Comment: Would you please share what your expected output should be?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT col_1 AS distinct_value
FROM mysql_tbl_name
WHERE col_1 IS NOT NULL

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT col2 AS distinct_value
FROM mysql_tbl_name
WHERE col2 IS NOT NULL
```

The above `sql` creates two temporary tables, each with one column and then joins both of them with `UNION` keyword to give you the result.

Please Note that the keyword `DISTINCT` removes duplicate records, and you must be sure about it because the results might be undesireable if the `sql` omits such records were `col_1` value is `NOT NULL` and `col2` value is also `NOT NULL`

Hope this is what you were expecting.